# Does a multi-engine ATP with single-engine commercial privileges provide single-engine instrument privileges?

Tags: faa-regulations, pilot-certification

Does a multi-engine ATP with single-engine commercial privileges provide single-engine instrument privileges?

I received my ATP certificate recently, and the back of my FAA certificate reads as follows.

```
AIRLINE TRANSPORT PILOT
  AIRPLANE MULTIENGINE LAND
  ...
COMMERCIAL PRIVILEGES
  AIRPLANE SINGLE ENGINE LAND
...
```

I left out the specific type ratings and limitations as noted by `...`.

The ATP supersedes an instrument rating, but the ATP is for the multi-engine category. Shouldn't the certificate reflect an instrument rating in the single-engine category?

The changes to my certificate were completed in IACRA and I have had part of a rating inadvertently removed before using the IACRA system.

Comment: http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=ffb9d4e1606645e6c94dc65b95a6b7fc&mc=true&node=se14.2.61_1167&rgn=div8

Comment: Since the Instrument addon is by category, not class, aka Instrument Airplane, or Instrument Rotorcraft, the ATP Multi-Engine Airplane, counts for Instrument Airplane for the Commercial Single.

Comment: I agree with slookabill, I don't believe there is any distinction for instrument, you have it or you don't, it's not tied to a class of aircraft like single or multi.

Comment: @slookabill you should post your comment as an answer. It's short but it's the correct one.

Comment: Note also that you **have** an *ATP Certificate*, which gives you instrument privileges.  On this certificate, there is a sub-section which states that you have *Commercial Privileges* for ASEL but that is still part of your ATP Certificate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note this is my interpretation of part 61. Double check with the FSDO for a more legally biding answer.

Since the Instrument addon is by category, not class, aka Instrument Airplane, or Instrument Rotorcraft, the ATP Multi-Engine Airplane, counts for Instrument Airplane for the Commercial Single.

Answer (score -2):

ATP certificates do NOT supersede an instrument rating.  Rather an instrument rating is a pre-requisite to obtain an ATPL.  See FAR 61.153 subpart d.1.

An instrument-airplane or instrument-rotorcraft helicopter rating is applicable to all classes or types of aircraft in that category.  I would think the ATPL would have an addendum to it stating INSTRUMENT-AIRPLANE.  I guess the FAA does not list it that way.

Comment: §61.167 (a) 1 ... an atp holder is entitled to the same privileges as someone who holds a commercial certificate and instrument rating, so that's probably why my ticket doesn't say instrument rated anymore. Your response doesn't directly address the question.